# Continue at relatively low paying job over a new job offer?

Tags: management, job-search, job-offer, new-job, negotiation

I am working in high-sized organization with 50K employee as a software developer. I am working on very boring project. As I am happy with the project I started job hunt, I got new offer with around 50% raise with some other high-sized.

Yesterday I resigned from my role stating primary reason as I was not happy with the work and money is secondary reason.

Due to company policy my existing employer cannot counter the offer. However, my manager has offered me a role in some exiciting project.

What could go wrong if I stay? will I always be perceived as someone who could abandon the ship? or should I take the new offer?

**[Edit]** 
30-50 % is an average hike in the country where I work.
To answer "Why would I want to raise after receiving the signigact offer?" I like the people with whom I work.

Comment: 50% raise is too good to let go. Accept the offer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Don't ask "What could go wrong if I stay". Ask "Why should I stay?"**

You have an opportunity to work somewhere else where you will get a healthy raise and potentially exiting new projects.

- What would keep you at your current company?
- Do you enjoy who you work with?
- Are you sure you won't just get one good project and be put back onto boring stuff?
- Are you always going to resent turning down that raise?

The decision is ultimately not one that can be answered on this site, but asking the right questions is a good first step!

Answer (score 3):

> What could go wrong if I stay? will I always be viewed as someone who could move anytime? or should I take the new offer?

You have already resigned, so if you stay you would at best be seen as someone who is indecisive and a flight risk.  What else could go wrong if you stayed:

- you will continue to be paid less money
- you may not like the new project and will be stuck in the same situation

A 50% raise in salary doesn't often come around, so while you may not be too worried about money at the moment, carefully consider the long term ramifications of having that extra income before you make a decision.

Answer (score 2):

We can't really give you advice on whether you should stay or not - that's a personal decision that you'll have to make for yourself. But we can answer your other questions,

> What could go wrong if I stay? will I always be viewed as someone who could move anytime?

Yes - generally, people who threaten to leave and then decide to stay are often seen as a risk in the future. Perhaps worse, you may be seen as having bluffed, and used the external offer as leverage to get what you want. No one likes to be deceived, and although your current manager seems to want to accommodate you, their positive attitude might not be shared elsewhere in your company.

Ultimately, if you have problems in your current workplace (whether that's being underpaid, or not liking your projects), **it's best to raise the issues and seek a resolution independently from threats of leaving.** Give your bosses a chance to fix problems. If they value you as an employee, they should be willing to do this. If they don't value you enough to solve your problems, well then - you have your answer.

But *forcing* the issue by mentioning an external offer will often leave you with a bad reputation, since you may be perceived as having not even bothered to give them the opportunity to fix things. You haven't mentioned in your question if you tried to resolve these issues prior to seeking an external offer, but if you hadn't, it may be appropriate to do so in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the risks:

- You'll be paid less money
- You'll be asked to remain with the old boring project for a couple of weeks to transition it to someone else
- Once you've burned your bridge with the new potential employer, the old employer will rescind his offer because he really needs you and no one has as much knowledge on the old project as you do.
- Or the new project won't be as exciting as he promised. And to work on that new project, you may be moved away from the co-workers you like so much.

Answer (score 1):

You're asking whether you should play the "counteroffer game."  That is, you get a better offer, then your present employer counters the offer.

It's a risky game to play for the obvious reasons. Your loyalty becomes suspect at your old employer. At the new employer, you waste their time by turning down an offer after they have decided they want you, which hurts your reputation.

It's a small world, and accepting or declining job offers is one of the most visible things you can do in that world.

You can play the "counteroffer game" maybe once, or maybe twice, in your entire career. Play it more than that and you damage your personal social capital. Plus, it makes you feel like a slimy toad. Ask me how I know this sometime.

You have a very weak counteroffer. There's no extra pay associated with it. It's not worth the risk of playing the game. Say, "thanks, but I have made my decision" and don't look back.

You can maintain good relationships with former colleagues, so all is not lost.